# Getting error on current month using javascript Date() function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I stuck with date functionality, have small requirement to show date with `DD-DD-YYYY HH:MM::SS`. Getting exact result on individual items `(curdate.getDate() , curdate.getMonth()+1 , curdate.getFullYear()...)`,  but at the time alerting the entire result, month value showing "11" insted of 2. Could any one help me please.

```
var curdate = new Date();
    var todaysDt = curdate.getDate()+ "-" + curdate.getMonth()+1 + "-" + curdate.getFullYear() + " " +curdate.getHours() + ":" + curdate.getMinutes() + ":" + curdate.getSeconds();
    todaysDt = todaysDt.split(/\/|-|\s|:/);
    alert(todaysDt);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5qkt8e06/101/)

Answer (score 2):

You have to parenthesize the subexpression where you add `1` to the month number:

```
var todaysDt = curdate.getDate()+ "-" + (curdate.getMonth()+1) + "-" + curdate.getFullYear() + " " +curdate.getHours() + ":" + curdate.getMinutes() + ":" + curdate.getSeconds();
```

That ensures that that subexpression — `(curdate.getMonth()+1)` — will be evaluated as a numeric addition operation. Outside those parentheses, you're concatenating strings with `+`. Why is that? Without explicit parentheses to dictate the order of evaluation, a chain of `+` operations is evaluated left-to-right. That is,

```
a + b + c + d + e
```

is evaluated as if it were explicitly punctuated

```
(((a + b) + c) + d) + e
```

Because in JavaScript string concatenation "wins" over arithmetic addition, having strings to the left in a chain of `+` operation effectively turns everything after that into string concatenation.

When you introduce *explicit* parentheses, you force that subexpression to be evaluated on its own. Because both the month value returned from `.getMonth()` and the constant `1` are numbers, that `+` will function as a numeric addition operator.

Answer (score 2):

without parenthesis it is concatenating `1+1` which shows 11 , but in actual you need sum , so use parenthesis around them, then it will perform sum.

```js
var curdate = new Date();
 var todaysDt = curdate.getDate()+ "-" + (curdate.getMonth()+1) + "-" + curdate.getFullYear() + " " +curdate.getHours() + ":" + curdate.getMinutes() + ":" + curdate.getSeconds();
 //todaysDt = todaysDt.split(/\/|-|\s|:/);
    alert(todaysDt);
```

Answer (score 0):

hope the format function can help you

```
Date.prototype.format = function(format) {
    var o = {
        "M+": this.getMonth() + 1, //month 
        "d+": this.getDate(), //day 
        "h+": this.getHours(), //hour 
        "m+": this.getMinutes(), //minute 
        "s+": this.getSeconds(), //second 
        "q+": Math.floor((this.getMonth() + 3) / 3), //quarter 
        "S": this.getMilliseconds() //millisecond 
    }

    if (/(y+)/.test(format)) {
        format = format.replace(RegExp.$1, (this.getFullYear() + "").substr(4 - RegExp.$1.length));
    }

    for (var k in o) {
        if (new RegExp("(" + k + ")").test(format)) {
            format = format.replace(RegExp.$1, RegExp.$1.length == 1 ? o[k] : ("00" + o[k]).substr(("" + o[k]).length));
        }
    }
    return format;
}
```